# Bash - Need to use exit but then call another function?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm writing a little script to use the webcam on the laptop and then email across the photo to me. The ffmpeg usage has to have a exit code for it to work so with this exit the mail function will not get called. What am I doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash

MAIL_ADDR=user@example.com
ts=`date +%s`
list=$(ls | tail -n 1)

function mcheese(){
mkdir /tmp/cheese
cd /tmp/cheese
echo -e "Cheese " | mutt -s "$TS Cheese" $MAIL_ADDR -a $list
}

function cheese(){
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -s vga -i /dev/video0 -vframes 3 /tmp/cheese/vid-$ts.%01d.jpg 
exit 0
}

cheese
mcheese
```

Comment: So what happens when you simply remove that `exit 0` ? Note that you can `return 0` from a function without exiting the whole script.

Comment: If you need the exit, can it be in a subshell? For example, `$(ffmpeg ... ; exit 0)`.

Comment: error when exit is removed - Can't stat yasm-1.1.0.tar.gz: No such file or directory
yasm-1.1.0.tar.gz: unable to attach file.

Comment: where does this `yasm-1.1.0.tar.gz` file appear?

Comment: in the root of the folder - so for this its /home/user/scripts/yasm-1.1.0

Comment: Who is needing that file?

Comment: Presumably `list` is `yasm-1.1.0.tar.gz`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You setup `list` in one directory, then change directory and use it.
This is unlikely to work.

Use `bash -x` to work out where your script is actually failing.

Comment: Ahh silly me - I was listing the root folder - working now :-)

Comment: @Grimlockz you can use this little trick to avoid problems when changing directories: `list=$(ls -d "$PWD"/* | tail -n 1)`. That way it will have the full path.